# How gmond get the Hadoop Metrics in Ganglia?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ganglia

I am exploring Hadoop monitoring with ganglia. It use gmond and gmetad demon which use for monitoring.

I would like to know that how gmond get the monitoring metrics from Hadoop ? does they use MBeans which expose by Hadoop or they do something more ?

Answer (score 1):

You set the metric context in the Hadoop and HBase configurations. To use Ganglia, you would set it to the GangliaContext or GangliaContext31. When configured, Hadoop and HBase will write out their metrics to gmond. It's a "push", not a "pull". The source code to the GangliaContext can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/metrics/ganglia/GangliaContext.java).

I believe the default is the NoEmitMetricsContext which, as the name implies, does not emit any metrics at all. You'll have to manually turn this on.